# Why won't my java display update? Bingo Card

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm working on a Bingo game and have gotten to where the user input number needs to be marked if it matches one of the randoms in the card and then I want the updated card to display. I can't seem to get the markings to show up, though. I feel like I'm supposed to update the string I'm printing out but I can't figure out how I would go about doing that.

````
public class BingoCard {


    public static void main (String[] args) {

      
       Random rando = new Random();
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   
       int [][] Card = new int [5][5];
   
       int userNum = 0;
       boolean BINGO;
       int start = 1;   

         


        //2D Array populating top to bottom and left to right
        for (int c = 0; c < Card[0].length; c++) {
            
            for (int r = 0; r < Card.length; r++) {
                   int pos = rando.nextInt(values.size()-1);
                   Card[r][c] = values.get(pos);
                   values.remove(pos);
   
            }//End of inner loop
            
           for (int i = start; i < 15; i++) {
               values.add(i);
               
           }//End for
         start += 15;
        }//End of outer loop

        //Free Space
        Card[2][2] = 0;
        
        



        System.out.println("Welcome to Bingo!");

        do {            
            //Display
            String str = "B\tI\tN\tG\tO\n";

            for (int r = 0; r < Card.length; r++) {
               for (int c = 0; c < Card[0].length; c++) {
                  if (Card[r][c] > 0) {
                    str += Card[r][c] + "\t";
                  }
                  else {
                    str += "X\t";
                  }//End else
                  
                  //Place Markers
                  for (int r2 = 0; r2 < Card.length; r2++) {
                      for (int c2 = 0; c2 < Card[0].length; c2++) {
                          if (Card[r2][c2] == userNum) {
                              Card[r2][c2] = 0;
                          }//End if
                      }//End inner
                  }//End outer
                     }//End inner loop
                  str += "\n";
                  }//End outer loop
            
            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println("Please enter the number called");
            userNum = in.nextInt();            

            int sumAcross = 0;
            int sumVertical = 0;
            int sumDiagR = 0;
            int sumDiagL = 0;

            for (int r = 0; r < Card.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < Card[0].length; c++) {
                    sumAcross += Card[r][c];
                    sumVertical += Card[c][r];

                }//End inner

                sumDiagR += Card[r][r];
                sumDiagL += Card[r][4-r]; //Inverts the diagonal. Check Array placements to understand better

                //Check win if all are 0
                if (sumAcross == 0 || sumVertical == 0) {
                    BINGO = true;
                }

                sumAcross = 0;
                sumVertical = 0;

            }//End outer

            if (sumDiagR == 0 || sumDiagL == 0) {
                BINGO = true;
            }
            else {
                BINGO = false;
            }


        } while (!BINGO);

    }//End main
}//End class```

Also, if anyone has any good java fundamental videos that explain everything like you're a toddler, I'd appreciate those greatly.
````

Comment: `if anyone has any good java fundamental videos that explain everything` - asking for that's [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site

Comment: Oh dang. And I get why. I just want to learn!

Comment: Your Bingo card has to keep track of whether a number is marked or unmarked, maybe with a plain Java getter / setter Cell class.  Perhaps this [Bingo Simulation](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/bingo-simulator) explanation and code might give you some ideas.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Gilbert!